# SVG child elements that affect it's parent

Tags: svg, properties, attributes, parent-child, element

Many of elements' properties in `SVG` are usually declared as `attributes` or `properties` inside the element. F.ex `width` and `height`:

```
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
```

However, there are some properties that can be expressed as child elements. These child elements are placed directly inside the parent element they are affecting. One of these child elements is `title`:

```
<svg width="500" height="300" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g>
    <title>SVG Title Demo example</title>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="200" height="50" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

In this case, the `title` applies to it's first parent, `g`.

**Does there exist a list of all parent affecting child elements like this?**

I need to know when to check element's children for additional definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've discovered the following child `elements` that affect their parent:

> **[Descriptive elements:](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermDescriptiveElement)**
>
> *An element which provides supplementary descriptive information about*
>   its parent.
>
> - **desc**
> - **metadata**
> - **title**

and:

> **[Filter primitive elements:](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermFilterPrimitiveElement)**
>
> *A filter primitive element is one that can be used as a child of a
>   **filter** element to specify a node in the filter graph.*
>
> - **feBlend**
> - **feColorMatrix**
> - **feComponentTransfer**
> - **feComposite**
> - **feConvolveMatrix**
> - **feDiffuseLighting**
> - **feDisplacementMap**
> - **feFlood**
> - **feGaussianBlur**
> - **feImage**
> - **feMerge**
> - **feMorphology**
> - **feOffset**
> - **feSpecularLighting**
> - **feTile**
> - **feTurbulence**